# Set GTL output in AMPSCRIPT variables

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, gtl

hope that someone can help me here:

I'm trying to retrieve a simple result from a POST api call into ampscript  variables. The cloudpage does show the variables as GTL, but when I try to display them as AMP script variables I get this as an output:

{{balance}} 
{{resetlink}} 
{{expirydate}}

This is the code I use:

```
%%=HTTPPost2('https://myurl','text/html', '', true, @Json)=%%  
%%{={{ }}=}%%
{{.datasource JSONVar source=@json type=variable}}
    {{.data}}
        { "target" : "@json" }
    {{/data}}

Balance = {{ balance }} <br>
Resetlink = {{ resetlink }} <br>
Expirydate = {{ expirydate }} <br>
%%[
SET @Saldo = TreatAsContent('{{balance}}')
SET @Reset = TreatAsContent('{{resetlink}}')
SET @Expiry = TreatAsContent('{{expirydate}}')
]%%

{{/datasource}}

%%=v(@Saldo)=%% <br>
%%=v(@Reset)=%% <br>
%%=v(@Expiry)=%%<br>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unfortunately it results in the same when I use double quotes :/

Comment: Removing my previous comment as it is incorrect, it is supposed to use the quotes on it.

Comment: I would try moving the `{{/datasource}}` below the var outputs.

Comment: I just learned from this example:
https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/046cea2a299fd0b2168637db74a5d9fe
That what I am trying to achieve does not work in cloudpages.
I guess I'll have to switch to SSJS

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape OMM delimiters when using GTL in CloudPages by prefixing your mustache tags with `%%{={{ }}=}%%`. For example:

```
SET @Saldo = TreatAsContent('%%{={{ }}=}%%{{balance}}')
```